# How to pass a .sol file as a parameter to a function? Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

A custom .sol file is created in the front-end. I need to compile and deploy the newly created contract using the external user as a signer, similar to how remix lets others deploy their own contracts.

To do this, my plan was to create a parent contract that compiles and deploys the new child contracts. These newly built child contracts could be passed to a function in the parent contract. Is this possible, and if so how can I do this?

Can I pass a .sol file as a parameter to a function in a solidity contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a compiled bytecode - not the Solidity source - to a factory contract which invokes the low-level `create` opcode, effectively deploying the contract that you just passed to it.

Here's an example of such factory contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Target {
    uint public number = 100;
}

contract Factory {
    event DeployedTo(address);

    function deploy(bytes memory code) public returns (address addr) {
        assembly {
            addr := create(0,add(code,0x20), mload(code))
        }

        emit DeployedTo(addr);
    }

    function deployTarget() public {
        this.deploy(
            hex"60806040526064600055348015601457600080fd5b50607d806100236000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c80638381f58a14602d575b600080fd5b603560005481565b60405190815260200160405180910390f3fea26469706673582212204222f4063ba77f82b7d8339b117fd0142d917b7d473221d6bb362a1467d5d83864736f6c63430008070033"
        );
    }
}
```

The `Target` is here just for reference. `deployTarget()` passes its bytecode to the `deploy()` function, and then you can validate its functionality in Remix by loading the `Target` contract at the deployed address (the blue button "At Address" on the screenshot).

[image: load contract at address]

[image: working Target contract]

Comment: Great, thank you so much. Is there a way I can programmatically convert a solidity contract into a compiled bytecode using ether.js or by another solidity contract?

Comment: @SuvanCheemalamarri The Solidity compiler is available as a JS package https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js, which you can use alongside ethers.js.